# Can I read the log file in a script, while the script is running, when the output of script is getting written to the same log file?

Tags: bash, shell, ksh

I have a shell script that writes output to some_log_file.log file.

```
{

some logic..

if grep -iq "No such file or directory" some_log_file.log ; then

some logic to send email.. attaching the same some_log_file.log

fi

} >> some_log_file.log 2>&1
```

If you observe the above code, the script is checking the same log file to which it is writing to, while running. this is working. But, is it allowed, and standard?

Comment: If your script writes that message to the log it should already know that an error has occured. Why read the log if you already know this? Makes no sense to me

Comment: It is allowed, but what's the point if the log file only contains messages from the script?

Comment: actually.. the error "No such file or directory" happens in a remote machine via ftp/sftp. in place of "echo error", I would actually send a mail. modified the script too.

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's allowed.  No, I don't think is very common or standard.
However since it is working, you can leave it like it is.

But to Panki's point: It would better and far more efficient to just to examine the exit status (a.k.a. return status) of the command that potentially reports "No such file or directory" rather than grep-ing the log.

The variable $? always contains the exit status of the last command executed.  Normally it is 0 which indicates the command ran successfully.  If it is a positive value (1, 2, 99, whatever) it indicates some type of failure.  For example:

```
>> ls /usr/bin/sed
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  202960 May  9 15:30 /usr/bin/sed
>> echo $?
0

>> ls -l nonexistent_file
ls: nonexistent_file: No such file or directory
>> echo $?
1
```

What is your command that potentially reports "No such file or directory", ftp?  For simplicity for the moment, let's say it is "ls".  Your script might look something like this:

```
ls $my_file  # Or whatever your command is.
if [ $? = 1 ]; then
    # Send mail ...
fi

# Alternatives:

ls $my_file  # Or whatever your command is.
if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    # Send mail ...
fi

ls $my_file  # Or whatever your command is.
status=$?
case $status in
    0) : ;;  # Success, do nothing.
    1) Send mail ... ;;
    *) echo "Error: \"ls $my_file\"." returned status $status."
       exit 99;;
esac
```

If your command is ftp, that is a command that with a more complex status code which is explained here:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes
```

and here:

```
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/ftp-service-svchost-inetinfo/ftp-status-codes-iis-7-and-later-versions
```

Also you could investigate using the tail command with the -f (follow) option.  For example, you could run a command like this in the background:

```
tail -f some_log_file.log | grep -iq "No such file or directory"
```

See the tail man (manual) page for more information.

But I think using the exit status ($?) would be your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

A script doing a blocking read on a file it's also appending to will usually end in a hung process.

The usual read and write workflow goes like this:  The script waits for the next line to appear, processes it, and writes some output, and goes back to waiting for the next line.

When the output is going to the same file that the script is reading, then eventually the script's reading catches up to the same point in the file where it's writing.  At that point the script waits for the next line, but lines won't appear until the script writes some, and that won't happen until the script reads some new lines.  The script is hung.

If other processes are also writing to the file, then this won't happen.  But it's usually a situation to avoid.